# PHP form to log-in to Flash App

Tags: php, apache-flex, authentication

Is it possible to log in to a Flash app with a PHP log-in form? I was thinking it could work something like this:

1. PHP form creates a new session
2. connect to the user database, validate.
3. store the log-in information in session variables
4. load the swf

Comment: Doesn't actionscript have the ability to do that?

Comment: I have an html page with the .swf in a standard size login box, say 300 x 250. I resize the .swf and hide, move, remove all of the other html elements. That works fine. It just seems really ugly. I was looking for a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if you store your sessions in the database in an open format like JSON or XML then you can have your SWF app lod that data from the database. The SWF app should also be able to get the cookies from the broswer so you can find the cookie that stores the session name check the database, or file system if you keep it in there and then work magic from there.